# what is the difference between du/dx and dx/du in u-substitution how do you know which one to use?

Tags: calculus, integration, substitution

when doing $u$ substitution sometimes they use $du/dx$ but other times they use $dx/du$ in the book to get $du$ and I am just confused which one to use and when as they change the answer of $du$ and if I do it wrong can lead to mistakes.

Comment: If you make a substitution of the form $u=f(x)$, then you have $du=f'(x)\,dx$. If you make a substitution of the form $x=g(u)$, then you have $dx=g'(x)\,du$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: you have a typo: $dx=g'(u)\, du$

Comment: @Bernard, yes, thanks.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson i see what you mean but could you give me an example because but  lets say$\int sin^2cosx dx$ says use u=sinx is given du/dx=cosx so then dx=du/cosx do they use du/dx but then $\int8/x^2+4dx$ uses dx/du as they say x=tanu=du/dx=2sec^2 dx=2sec^2

Comment: If you want people to understand your question, Mary, you have to write a lot more. Please give an example of a function $h(x)$ and a substitution $u$ where you use $du/dx$ to find $\int\,h(x)$, and a function $j(x)$ and a substitution $u$ where you use $dx/du$ to find $\int\,j(x)$.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson i edited my comment but I think I understand what you mean and while writing it undurstod it thank you very much!

Comment: OK, that's good – but, look, it's exactly what I wrote: for the substitution $u=\sin x$, use $du=\cos x\,dx$, and for the substitution $x=\tan u$ use $dx=\sec^2u\,du$.

Comment: i seee thank you very very much!